# Device for boot loader installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, software-installation, bootloader

[Device for boot loader installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwrGD.jpg)

What should I select?
I am new to linux and I don't know what to do

Answer (score 1):

Boot loader goes to a device (usually drive, be it hdd, ssd etc).

Partitions are located on devices/drives, but are **not** devices. Most of the options listed are partitions and thus not appropriate (the first sector of a drive is reserved for the MBR where boot loader is placed, if you select a partition, you'll just lose the first 512 bytes of that partition with no benefit; just potential for data loss).

`/dev/neme0n1`  is the only device offered (the others are partitions).

Comment: Launchpad bug 1396379 still applies to Ubuntu 22.04 -- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Grub installs to wrong disk. If a second device were offered, user input will be ignored and the first device used. The subiquity installer for Ubuntu 23.04 has fixed this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a UEFI capable system.

**Select `/dev/neme0n1`.**

Note, when you select this, the installer is intelligent enough to install the boot loader to the correct partition. In your case, it will be `/dev/nvme0n1p1` and this partition will be mounted as `/boot/efi` in Ubuntu.